# How to get data from Task after running Task.WhenAll(taks)

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have multiple Async methods that I can run one by one but When I Use Task.WhenAll, I really don't know how to get the result. Following are my Async methods

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>> Method1Async()
    {
        return await Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>>.Run<IEnumerable<MyModel>>(() => GetMethod1Data());
    }
    //Here Method1Async().Result will get me the data but don't know how to get the result when I am using Task.WhenAll() 

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>> Method2Async()
    {
        return await Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>>.Run<IEnumerable<MyModel>>(() => GetMethod2Data());
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>> Method3Async()
    {
        return await Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>>.Run<IEnumerable<MyModel>>(() => GetMethod3Data());
    }
```

And here is my code where I am using Task.WhenAll

```
    public async Task GetDataAsync()
    {
        Task[] tasks = new Task[3];

        tasks[0] = Method1Async();
        tasks[1] = Method2Async();
        tasks[2] = Method2Async();

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Now if I call

> GetDataAsync()

method, I get all ok but don't know how to get the result from the returned task?

Comment: it will be an `Array[IEnumerable<MYModel>]`

Comment: As an aside, `Run` is a static method on `Task`. There's no need to use `Task<T>.Run`. And the arguments for `Run` should be inferred. `Task.Run(() => GetMethod1Data())` is all that's required.

Answer (score 0):

It will return an Array of type `IEnumerable<MyModel>` so you can set the return type of your async method to that :

```
public Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>[]> GetDataAsync()
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[3];

    tasks[0] = staticDataService.Method1Async();
    tasks[1] = staticDataService.Method2Async();
    tasks[2] = staticDataService.Method3Async();

    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

and then consume it:

```
IEnumerable<MyModel>[] results = await GetDataAsync();
```

Comment: You'll need a return, `return await ...`.

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi for fixing it, yes obviously we don't need to make it asynchrounous when using `Task.WhenAll` in this case

Comment: I appreciate Charles, NKosi and Ehsan for the replies. Would please someone tell how I will call GetDataAsync() if the caller method is not async method

Comment: @LearningCurve `IEnumerable<MyModel>[] results = GetDataAsync().Result;` that's how

Comment: As @Ehsan suggested, await GetDataAsync is the way, but I am calling this method from a synchronous method.

Comment: @Kunal, It is not giving me the option of getting result from GetDataAsync(). Am I missing some reference here? I Initially started with this approach but without Result available I started looking in other directions

Comment: @LearningCurve it is one or the other, do not mix. I would suggest then an async event handler.

Comment: or the method should not be async if the consumer needs to invoked it syncronously ?

Comment: Let's say if I am not using async event handler, Why I am unable to get the result out ov the task?

Comment: @LearningCurve `IEnumerable<MyModel>[] results = GetDataAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` try with this one, it will fetch the result of the task synchronously

Comment: @LearningCurve there are ways, but that's not normally preferred.

Comment: @Kunal, your suggested result gives the error of  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyModel>[]'

Comment: I am actually lost here.. Valuable inputs by all of you guys but I am still unable to figure out the right answer/implementation.

Comment: @LearningCurve `IEnumerable<MyModel>[] results = GetDataAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` use this code coupled with @Ehsan's answer if you are calling it in a synchronous method. Since the return type of your code is async Task it will return a void when we do `.GetResult()` hence `unable to implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyModel>[]`.

Comment: @Kunal, Ehsan answer complaining at return Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false). Cannot implicitly convert type 'Syste.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable' to 'System.Tasks.Task<System.Collection.Generic.Ineumerable<MyModel>[]>'